# How to implement swipeable TextView

Tags: android

I am trying to get a swipeable TextView but I have no idea how to do it.

I have a TextView with a OngestureListener which shows a month like "September 2013".
On right-swipe over the view the text changes to "August 2013".

Now i want, that while swiping the August is slighty visible on the left. Maybe I could use a TabHost or something like that but I don't know how to do it.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You might want to check [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/) about swipe/fling animation with a gestureDetector. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sounds like you need a ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks, the ViewPager got it working :)